# How can I deploy Zend Framework modules on different aliases?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a Zend Framework application with multiple modules that I'm trying to deploy.  I also have a non-ZF PHP appliaction that is already up on the DocumentRoot that needs to be preserved.

Basically, I need to go to the ZF application on certain aliases, but the default should be the DocumentRoot.  Can anyone think of a way to do that?

`mysite.com/ -> non-ZF application`

`mysite.com/module1 -> ZF application, module 1`

`mysite.com/module2 -> ZF application, module 2`

Anything after `mysite.com/` other than module1 and module2 should go to the non-ZF application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A combination of Apache aliases and Zend_Router rules should do the trick : 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html